# How to implement both device_preview and auto_route packages in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I would like to use both `device_preview` and `auto_route`. To do so, I need to add the respective codes to the builder property of `MaterialApp`. However, since there is only one builder property in `MaterialApp` widget, I can only use one of the packages. What can I do to use both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The builder property in Material App will give you context and a Native navigator in case you want to wrap it with some theme data or something, so instead of passing the native navigator pass your ExtendedNavigator.

```dart
MaterialApp(
      builder: (context, nativeNavigator) => DevicePreview.appBuilder(
        context,
        ExtendedNavigator(router: Router()),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is using `auto_route` in version `0.6.2` or above, you might be struggling with the solution, as the answer above doesn't work anymore, since auto_route is using `ExtendedNavigator.builder` now. This is how you can solve the issue:

```
MaterialApp(
  locale: DevicePreview.of(context).locale,
  builder: (context, nativeNavigator) => DevicePreview.appBuilder(
    context,
    ExtendedNavigator.builder<Router>(
      router: Router(),
    )(context, nativeNavigator),
  ),
);
```